# Linker issue in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get started with C++ in VS 2017 (empty project template), but immediately ran into linker problems when adding 1 simple class, so I guess I'm missing something important...

My project looks like this:

[image: project structure]

`test.h`:

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    test();
    ~test();

    std::string getInfo();
};
```

`test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

test::test() {}
test::~test() {}

std::string getInfo() {
    return "test";
}
```

And `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    test t;
    std::cout << "output: " << t.getInfo() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The linker error I get is the infamous LNK2019:

`LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl test::getInfo(void)" (?getInfo@test@@QEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function main`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: `std::string getInfo()` in test.cpp defines a free function, not a `test` member function. You forgot to resolve the scope: `std::string test::getInfo()`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that solved it, just put it in an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Thank you for the offer, and as much as I'd love the extra reputation, I've already voted to close the question as being effectively a typo. It would be gauche at this point for me to post an answer.

Comment: Yep, typo questions are best closed and deleted to reduce clutter in search results.  Someone with a non-typo linker problem will find a fix more easily without reading this.

Comment: Alright, well thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In file `test.cpp` you need to properly specify the scope of the member function:

```
std::string test::getInfo() {
    return "test";
}
```

Note the `test::` before the `getInfo()`